# How to configure tomcat to serve precompressed static files?

Tags: tomcat, gzip, static-files

Under nginx I know a option:

```
gzip_static on;
```

which allows to access the precompressed `gzip` file with the same name, for example, if I have a file `/var/www/style.css.gz`, when request http://localhost/style.css with header '
`Accept-Encoding:gzip` the server will return the file on disk `style.css.gz` as `style.css`.

How can I do the same under `Tomcat`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Tomcat doesn't have this feature.</s>

You could write a servlet/filter/etc. that can do it if you'd like.

Starting with Tomcat 8.5, you can set the `precompressed` flag in `web.xml` to do this. You have to either modify `conf/web.xml` to enable this site-wide, or copy the configuration for the `DefaultServlet` from `conf/web.xml` into your application's `WEB-INF/web.xml`.

You must set an `<init-param>` with the name `precompressed` to `true`, like this:

```
<init-param>
  <param-name>precompressed</param-name>
  <param-value>true</param-value>
</init-param>
```

There are other options available, so you should [read about Tomcat's DefaultServlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/default-servlet.html) for more information.

In Tomcat 8.0, the option is called `gzip` and is similar to above. You should [read about Tomcat's DefaultServlet](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/default-servlet.html) in Tomcat 8.0 if you are using it. **Please note that Tomcat 8 has reached EOL and should no longer be used.**

Comment: Sorry, this answer is no longer true.

Comment: @flob I've updated the answer with full details.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for taking that effort and making it more concise :-)

Answer (score 5):

You can set the precompressed flag in web.xml to do this: https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-9.0-doc/default-servlet.html#where

Comment: Was also possible in Tomcat 8.0 using [`gzip=true`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/default-servlet.html#change)